# How can I debug this FQL PHP Query error?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm tring to get the sample on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ to work and I'm getting a generic error (see image below)

[image]

Here is the code I've placed on the page:

```
<?php
  $app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
  $my_url = 'POST_AUTH_URL';

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  //auth user
  if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

  //get user access_token
  $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
    . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
    . '&code=' . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  // Run fql query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
    . '&' . $access_token;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  //display results of fql query
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r("query results:");
  print_r($fql_query_obj);
  echo '</pre>';
```

How could I start to debug this?  The debug tool was no help

Comment: Yes, if you really need to know, I'm posting the question for a friend who only sent an image

Comment: That's fine, I was a little curious because it's a little unusual is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error doesn't related to FQL at all and displayed because Facebook fail to load your application. Ensure you have configured properly both "Canvas URL" and "Secure Canvas URL".